# JSON object instead of array when a single element is present on XML SOAP response

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, soap

I am consuming a web service that returns some XML data. The problems start when I convert the xml data to json. Some elements that are supposed to return an array of objects, when they have only one value, they are not converted to an array with a single object inside, they turn into an object. So instead of having:

```
{
"products":[ { "title":"Title 1",  "attributes":[{"color":"blue"}] } ]
}
```

I get

```
{
"products":{ "title":"Title 1", "attributes":{"color":"blue"} }
}
```

and the php array looks like this

`[products] => Array ( [title] => Title 1 [attributes] => Array ( [color] => blue ) )`

instead of this

`[products] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => Title 1 
                                      [attributes] => Array ([0] => Array ([color] => blue ) ) )`

So what I have done is the below:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($messageData);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

 if (isset($array['products']) && !isset($array['products'][0])) {
       $array['products'] = array($array['products']);
 }
```

I check if there is an array named products and if it doesn't have an index 0, I nest it inside a new array.
This does the job. Then I do the same for the attributes array like this:

```
    $products = $array['products'];

    $array['products'] = [];

    foreach ($products as $product) {

        if (isset($product['attributes']) && !isset($product['attributes'][0])) {

            $product['attributes'] = array($product['attributes']);

        }

        array_push($array['products'], product);
    }
```

Here, I bind the products array to a variable called `products` to use it in the loop, then I empty the array and after I create the new attributes array, I populate the products array with the changed products.

My question is:

Is there a better way to deal with this thing? I don't like what I am doing here, but I can't think of anything else...

**EDIT**

This is my soap request:

```
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $soapOptions);

    $soapHeader = WsSecurity::createWsSecuritySoapHeader($username, $password, false, $synced, 60, true, true, false, true);

    $client->__setSoapHeaders($soapHeader);

    $response = $client->dateRetrieveMovement($dateMovementRequest);

    $movements = $response->DateMovementRequestResult->movements;
    $movementInfo = $movements->movementInfo;
    $messages = $movementInfo->messages->messageExchanged;

    $messageData = $messages->IEMessage->xmlData;

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($messageData);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Comment: Can you show some sample XML that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I don't deal with actual XML at any point and I do not control the web service. I use a soap client, I make the request and then I pass the response on the `simplexml_load_string()` function...

Comment: What I've done here serves the purpose, but I would like to know if it could be done in a sleeker way...

Comment: If we have a very small xml sample, I am sure we will be able to help you better

Comment: So var dump of messageData :)

Comment: Guys, if you are familiar with soap client, you should know that it does not return actual xml, it returns an object... If you want I can show you the xsds, but I don't know how this will help...

Answer (score 0):

The question is "is there a better way of doing the XML to JSON conversion", and I think the answer is "not without doing some coding".

Standard XML-to-JSON conversion libraries simply don't know enough about the semantics of your data model to produce a decent representation of your data. In theory a tool could try an extract such information from a schema, or elsewhere, but I don't know of any that does.

Writing a custom XSLT transformation to produce exactly the JSON you want is not too difficult, especially with XSLT 3.0, and this may well be less effort than patching up the JSON in the receiving application in the way you describe.

Comment: This seems like an answer to the right direction. It's the first time I am in need of dealing with XML and as of now it's a very frustrating experience. From what I understand, if the soap client uses wsdl files to encode/decode the data sent and received, do I have to "inject" an xslt file between the two to make the appropriate changes or is there a different approach to make the request?

Comment: Structuring your application as a pipeline of transformation stages is generally good practice and is supported by many application frameworks, so injecting an XSLT transformation step should feel normal and natural.

Comment: Mr. Kay, I read a few things on XSLT, I watched a few tutorials, I even stumbled on your presentation on transforming JSON using XSLT 3.0. Unfortunately, right now I don't have a solid understanding of the concept and I don't think I can get through this as easy as I'd have imagined. If you are kind enough to point me to any resources relevant to the task I need to accomplish or any tools I should be using or what steps I should take, I would appreciate it. Regardless, I would like to thank you for taking the time to guide me to the right path.

Comment: @gothaf There are many books, tutorials, training courses, and what works for you depends on your own learning style. Some people just read the W3C spec: it's not as daunting as you might think, and has lots of good examples! But as with any new language there is a learning curve and you have to work at it to become proficient.